# @font-face not loading in shadowDom

Tags: html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

```
  this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: SpaceGrotesk;
      src: url(/fonts/SpaceGrotesk-Medium.ttf);
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: SpaceGroteskLight;
      src: url(/fonts/SpaceGrotesk-Light.ttf);
    }
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .tipme {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      font-family: SpaceGrotesk, sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 4rem 1.4rem 1.4rem;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
      margin: 5rem 1.4rem 1.4rem;
      width: 50rem;
    }

    h1 {
      font-family: SpaceGroteskLight, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 2.6rem;
      margin: 1rem;
    }
`;
```

The browser is not requesting the the font files.

I tried in incognito mode so its not a cache issue.

This is a distributed component running on multiple sites, so I cannot just load the font in the parent html. It needs to be encapsulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just dynamically adding style loading fonts to parent page:

```
this.fonts = `
        @font-face {
            font-family: SpaceGrotesk;
            src: url(${this.host}/fonts/SpaceGrotesk-Medium.ttf);
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: SpaceGroteskLight;
            src: url(${this.host}/fonts/SpaceGrotesk-Light.ttf);
        }
        `;



const style = document.querySelector('style[data-description="tipme-fonts"]');
        if (!style) {
            const el = document.createElement('style');
            el.dataset.description = 'tipme-fonts';
            el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.fonts));
            document.head.appendChild(el);
        }
```